# Create new database table ruby on rails schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

On my ruby on rails app i added following code in schema.rb file to create a new table in database

```
create_table "label_info", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "label_id"
  end
```

and then run rake db:migrate command  but nothing is happening. I thought it would create a new table in database .

Comment: I suggest you read [Active Record Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you read the first line of your `schema.rb` file you will see:

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
```

I would recommand to do `rails g model label_info`

Answer (score 0):

May be delete `:force => true`, because since you haven't created the table it keeps to create first.

> **:force** Set to true to drop the table before creating it. Defaults to false.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to destroy the model and recreate it or you have to change the migration number and rename the file, for the older schema version. You can use current time stamp. like `20150808114518_abc_xyz.rb`

Thanks!